# Which is better ifram or <video> to play video (both youtube as well non youtube) in terms of browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, video

I tried with both

1. iframe - no solution to stop autoplay or control video for non-youtube videos
2. video - Does not support youtube video

Using iframe

```
 <iframe id="vt" width="420" autoplay="false" height="345" src="http://cache4.asset-cache.net/xd/468140002.mp4?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=72990B68305E4FDFEE95B69A879131BCD6D7111452E48A17C03F8342D660D5A451EBC1DEC2A827C9&b=RTdG" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

   // var url = $('#vt').attr('src');
 // $('#vt').attr('src', '');
 //   $('#vt').attr('src', url);
    var vid = document.getElementById("vt");
    vid.pause()
//vid.onpause = function() {
    //alert("The video has been paused");
};
});
```

with video tag

```
<video width="320"  height="240" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwH34mR6ZG8" controls="controls"> </video>
```

Comment: You might want to post some code in your question...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, iframes were never meant for displaying embedded media. That's something the *object* tag was intended to handle instead. From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#embedded_content):

> The *HTML Inline Frame Element* (`<iframe>`) represents a nested browsing
>   context, **effectively embedding another HTML page into the current
>   page.**
>
> The *HTML Embedded Object Element* (`<object>`) represents an external
>   resource, which can be treated as an image, a nested browsing context,
>   **or a resource to be handled by a plugin.**

Both of which predate the `video` element, which is what you should always be using to embed video content in a webpage.

Secondly, YouTube videos aren't meant to be linked directly from a `<video>` element... the embed code they provide you with is an iframe that opens up to an HTML5 video player anyway (or a Flash fallback for antique devices).

**Verdict:** If the video you're trying to display isn't or can't be hosted on YouTube, use the `video` tag on a webpage to embed it, making sure to convert the video in as many supported formats as possible. There's plenty of write-ups online on HTML5 video, so I won't detail the process here.